# std::bad_alloc thrown on prime number task

Tags: c++, primes, dynamic-allocation, bad-alloc

I am working on a task in which I have to print out all the prime numbers between two given numbers, but which are also palindromes. The program crashes, however, throwing an std::bad_alloc. I have tried fixing this by dynamically allocating my two main arrays on the heap, but this did not fix anything. Can anybody please help me fix this error? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int mini, maxi;
int *list = new int[10000002];
int *visited = new int[10000002];

bool is_pal(string num)
{
    string num2 = num;
    reverse(num2.begin(), num2.end());
    if (num2 == num)
        return true;
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    visited[4] = 1;
    visited[6] = 1;
    visited[8] = 1;
    visited[9] = 1;
    cin >> mini >> maxi;
    for (int i = mini; i <= maxi; i++)
        list[i] = i;
    for (int i = mini; i <= maxi; i++)
    {
        if (visited[i] == 0)
        {
            for (int j = i * 2; j <= maxi; j += i)
            {
                visited[j] = 1;
                list[j] = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = mini; i <= maxi; i++)
        if (visited[i] == 0 && is_pal(to_string(list[i])))
            cout << list[i] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be able to get a `bad_alloc` unless you allocate dynamically. If you threw 80+ MB on the stack, it's almost certain to overflow, though.

Comment: I did allocate dynamically!

Comment: I originally declared it on the stack, it caused the same problem...

Comment: Did you `int *list = new int[10000002];` inside a function or `int list [10000002];`? Most computers these days should be able to give you 80 GB contiguous dynamic storage and avoid the `bad_alloc`. I can't reproduce. The algorithm doesn't seem to work, but's not terminating with an allocation error.

Comment: It's exactly what you can see in my code - I declared it globally, outside of a function.

Comment: program runs fine w/ gcc 6.3.0. No `bad_alloc`s. What values did you enter for `mini` and `maxi` ?

Comment: 5 for mini, 500 for maxi...

Comment: How much available RAM does your computer have? You're not trying to run this on an Arduino or anything like that, are you?

Comment: What happens if you use Automatic allocation? `int list[1002];` and `int visited[1002];` Note the small size just to prove out where the problem is.

Comment: it works just fine with both stack and heap allocation if I remove a couple zeroes, but it requires more space for large mini and maxi input values that are on the way... (also, my pc has 8GB ram).

Comment: Perhaps there is an out-of-bounds subscript...?

Comment: I can't find one, however... can anybody see a problem with out-of-bounds?

Comment: Only way you should be able to get `bad_alloc` is to ask for dynamic storage that cannot be supplied. Technically out of bounds access can do anything, but I've never seen one toss a phantom exception.

Comment: this is very odd indeed that this is happening... any ideas as to why?

Comment: If you want to test for out of bounds, use `std::array` or `std::vector` and swap the `[]`s for the `at` method. `at` bounds checks.

Comment: I changed from arrays to vectors and got the exact same result... std::bad_alloc...

Comment: Somehow you do not have enough contiguous free memory or you have a mega-weird. Run the program through whatever debugger came with your development environment and see where the exception is thrown. What development tools are you using?

Comment: Huh. One other possibility: Build error and you're executing stale code. Let's remove all dynamic allocation from the program. Replace `int *list = new int[10000002];
int *visited = new int[10000002];` with `int list[10000002];
int visited [10000002];`. Note that this still won't work, algorithm is broken, but if you still get `bad_alloc` when there are no dynamic allocations in the program, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: ah, yes... now it says that I am going out-of-bounds... do you know where this is happening?

Comment: [That's a job for the debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger). Trust me, you want to get good at using debuggers. It's unlikely that you will encounter a better programming productivity tool, and the sooner you get good at using them, the sooner you can start getting your programs done faster.

Comment: Plus the debugger will help you see where you're going wrong in your sieving algorithm.